# wanted to know about Finished processing dependencies for pyparsing==2.0.1

Tags: python

currently i am trying to install pyparsing when i run

```
>>> easy_install http://cheeseshop.python.org/packages/source/p/pyparsing/pyparsing-2.0.1.tar.gz
```

at the end the below mentioned line appears. i just wanted to know what does this means?

```
Finished processing dependencies for pyparsing==2.0.1
```

Comment: It means what it says: "Finished processing dependencies for pyparsing==2.0.1".

Comment: @LutzHorn If the meaning of this was obvious to the OP, I don't think they would be asking the question.

Comment: How much more obvious could it be?

Comment: the issue was that despite it displayed finished processing dependencies for pyparsing==2.0.1 when ever i try to import it it says pyparsing missing, that's why i asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each package on the Python Package Index (PyPI) has dependencies declared in a file associated with the package. That is, `pyparsing` may depend on other packages which must be installed in order for it to work. `easy_install` recognizes this, so it will automatically make sure the dependencies are installed when you try to install `pypasrsing`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply
so if i install some package will the easy_install take care of installation of per-recordists?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "per-recordists"?